# Why do image and picture elements display images despite http status 404?

Tags: html, image, web-standards

The following request returns an HTTP status code of 404, but also `content-type: image/jpeg` and valid JPEG data in the response body:

`https://img.youtube.com/vi/lXMskKTw3Bc/maxresdefault.jpg`

If you set this as the `src` of an image, the image will still be displayed. Furthermore, an `onerror` event is not triggered, so I can't use `onerror="this.src=this.src.replace('maxres', 'sd')"` to trigger a fallback.

This behaviour is consistent across Firefox/Chrome/Edge, so I wonder **1) if this is something defined in the standards**? Or is it actually a bug that exists in all major browsers?

Using it as a source in a `picture` element will also not have it fall back to the next available image size and display the "broken" image as well.

```html
<h3>Plain image element:</h3>
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/lXMskKTw3Bc/maxresdefault.jpg" onerror="this.src=this.src.replace('maxres', 'sd')">

<h3>Picture element:</h3>
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 640px)" srcset="https://img.youtube.com/vi/lXMskKTw3Bc/sddefault.jpg">
  <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="https://img.youtube.com/vi/lXMskKTw3Bc/hqdefault.jpg">
  <source media="(max-width: 320px)" srcset="https://img.youtube.com/vi/lXMskKTw3Bc/mqdefault.jpg">
  <source srcset="https://img.youtube.com/vi/lXMskKTw3Bc/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/lXMskKTw3Bc/sddefault.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
</picture>

<h3>expected output:</h3>
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/lXMskKTw3Bc/sddefault.jpg">
```

**2) Is there a way to circumvent this and fall back to the next smaller image size that doesn't result in a 404 status, *preferrably without using JavaScript*?**

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) states that `onerror` is thrown when the image **"fails to load"**. In your case, the image has loaded successfully; it's just accompanied by a 404 notifying you that it is not the image that you originally requested.

Comment: OK, I would have expected the 404 to take precedence over valid image data, or at least trigger the error event in addition to displaying the image. But it seems like it's not regarded as an error at all, so I guess there's no way around it other than checking the request via JS (or in this specific case checking the YouTube API via JS and only take the image sizes into account that it returns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tyler Roper for his comment:

> The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) states that `onerror` is thrown when the image **"fails to load"**. In your case, the image has loaded successfully; it's just accompanied by a 404 notifying you that it is not the image that you originally requested.

For my specific case, I solved it this way:

```html
<img
  src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/lXMskKTw3Bc/maxresdefault.jpg"
  onload="if (this.naturalWidth < 1280) { this.src = this.src.replace('maxres', 'sd') }">
```

So, it loads the `maxresdefault` first, which should normally be at least 1280px wide. If it's less, the image source is changed to `sddefault`.